# "The resouce "Project name" is not accessible for launching" in eclipse

Tags: java, android

The changes made in the code was not getting updated on output in the emulator, even after trying many ways could not get the solution, so finaly reinstalled everything, now the project is getting updated for android version 4.2, not for all versions of projects, android projects versions apart from 4.2 are not getting opened, for newly imported projects are openable, i have installed various version like 2.2 2.3 til 4.2(old workspace).
When tried to run them this is the error message i get `"The resouce "Project name" is not accessible for launching"`, on right click of the project properties i'm not able to find android option. have anybody experienced this kind off issue?

Answer (score 0):

First go to Help --> Install new software --> Add this site link to download android plugin http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ ...

I know you must have done that in your previous installation...

If link exist.. start installing software by selecting all available...

Then Goto Help --> Check for updates and follow the steps...

Once done.. restart your eclipse...